# How to send a Map Object With FormData to .NET API?

Tags: javascript, .net, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

When i try to send a map object with FormData its give an error like;

> TS2345: Argument of type 'Map<number, number>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.   Type 'Map<number, number>' is missing the following properties from type 'Blob': type, arrayBuffer, slice, stream, tex

How can i send this object with formdata to my .net API ?

Comment: If possbile, could you please show a sample code you are trying at your side to send data to .net api? as the above error code is not giving much idea about the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to json and send like this

```
var content = '{ json data here }';
var blob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/json"});
formData.append("jsonData", blob);
```

OR

```
new Blob([JSON.stringify({
   description: 'description',
})], {
   type: 'application/json'
})
```